# XCode 13.1 very slow on large class

Tags: xcode, xcode13

I have downloaded recently XCode 13.1 and Monterey 12.1 to my Macbook Pro 2019 i9. In some large classes like 2000 lines and more, XCode slows down and writing code becomes big pain. Sometimes I cannot even write because it is so slow.

Also I often meet XCode crashes on my storyboards or even code files.

Tested this on other XCode versions and did not meet same issue. Anyone experiences this and knows how to fix?

Comment: Xcode becomes slower and slower and slower ... with each new update ..., but having a class with 2k+ lines is really bad - think about separating things: decompose and use dependency injection. Refactoring, refactoring ... and refactoring :)

Comment: Yes I know but this is another case. Thanks though.

Comment: yes , I am also face this issue in last few days after update the macOS and Xcode. Please tell if any suggestions..